# Disable useNavigate in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, storybook

I have an entire page component that has some navigation functionality.
I would like to display said page in Storybook.
I have installed the `storybook-addon-react-router-v6` addon but it does not prevent navigating, but it has no option to prevent navigating.
The component uses `useParams` but the params must be present in the url, and there's not option to "mock" the return value of `useParams` to always return the ones I want.

In the story, I define:

```
  parameters: {
    reactRouter: {
      routePath: '/:flowId/:executionId',
      routeParams: { executionId: mockExecutionId, flowId: mockFlowId },
    },
  },
```

Defining a params without providing the route placeholders doesn't actually make the params available.
And rhe `routePath` is only initial, and can be navigated out of. But I would like either the path, or the params to persist, which I cannot seem to be able to do.

And so I would like to prevent navigating altogether.
I am using vite, Storybook 7 and react-router-dom 6.
When I asked on Storybook's Discord, they suggested doing something like this:

1. Create a mock module:

```
// .storybook/mocks/react-router-dom.ts
import * as rrd from 'react-router-dom';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';

const mockRRD = {
  ...rrd,
  useNavigate: () => action('Navigation')
} as typeof rrd;

export default mockRRD;
```

2. Use `viteFinal` to replace the mocked module in the config.

```
// .storybook/main.ts
...
  viteFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    (config.resolve ?? (config.resolve = {})).alias = {
      'react-router-dom': './.storybook/mocks/react-router-dom.ts',
    }
    return config
  }
...
```

This throws an error saying it's missing some import types.

If I use `path.resolve(__dirname, './mocks/react-router-dom.ts')` it throws *many* errors, one per import, saying that there's no such export.

Anything else just throws an error saying the file doesn't exist.

I'm looking for a way to disable navigation, or alternatively use the same params regardless of path inside my story.